# How do I correct this PHP syntax

Tags: php

I created a Form with inputs named name, and msg;

I have:

```
$q /* My SQL query */ = "INSERT INTO posts ('NOW(),$_POST['name'],$_POST['msg']')";
```

in my PHP; after deploying the file I get a 500 error.

I know this code is bugged because after taking it out the page loads fine.
How do I fix it, I'm guessing its to do with quotation marks?

I think I could concatenate the posted data - using periods - instead of inputting straight into the string, but isn't it possible to do it in the cleaner, nicer, way?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) may be of interest to you

Comment: Use quotes for string value `$q = "INSERT INTO posts (NOW(), '".$_POST["name"]."', '".$_POST["msg"]."')";`

Answer (score 2):

The issue does have to do with quotes.  Here is a way to fix it:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO posts (NOW(), '{$_POST['name']}', '{$_POST['msg']}')";
```

> Note that it is extremely important to use prepared statements when
>   dealing with user input to prevent SQL injections.

The PHP manual includes a [great page on prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: U have extra single quote at end

Comment: I know this is a separate question but do you know of a quick-fix to "prepare" the statement in this context?

Comment: Looks fine but open for SQL injections

Comment: @devpro, Is the yellow background note too hard to see?

Comment: @WorstForum:  I included a link to the PHP manual page on prepared statements.

Comment: Edited just now :p